# Using flexbox to display tournament brackets

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to use `flexbox` to display a tournament bracket much like the NCAA bracket. Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/yibdRHJQEmB3yttwikgD?p=preview):

```css
@import "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css";
.game {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 2px;
}
.game:after {
  content: 'game';
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 384px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <!--Round 1-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 2-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 3-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 4-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class=game></div>
    <div class=game></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 5-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class=game></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am no CSS expert, but my thought process was if the number of `divs` in every column was exactly half compared to the previous one and if `space-around` were used, then the divs should automatically align correctly (centered between the previous rounds games). They are somewhat aligned but not exactly centered between the right games. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that bootstrap inserts some pseudo-elements which add additional space at the top and bottom:

```css
.container::after, .container::before {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
```

So just remove bootstrap and add this:

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.game {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 2px;
}
.game:after {
  content: 'game';
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 384px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <!--Round 1-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 2-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 3-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 4-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class=game></div>
    <div class=game></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 5-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class=game></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use bootstrap but avoid the `container` class:

```css
@import "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css";
.game {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 2px;
}
.game:after {
  content: 'game';
}
.row > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 384px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <!--Round 1-->
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 2-->
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 3-->
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 4-->
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class=game></div>
    <div class=game></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 5-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class=game></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! What is bootstrap doing that is causing the offset? Does this mean I can't use bootstrap on my page?

Answer (score 2):

Just float your brackets so they are arranged horizontally instead of vertically: `.container{float:left;}`

[image]

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
.game {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 2px;

}
.game:after {
  content: 'game';
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height:384px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <!--Round 1-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 2-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 3-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 4-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class=game></div>
    <div class=game></div>
  </div>
  <!--Round 5-->
  <div class="container col-sm-1">
    <div class=game></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me...just add float:left to the .container. I forked your plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/dA2iD8oJ0YTj5T1vG7B8?p=preview

Comment: I must be missing something - even your plunk doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Strange...this `float:left` fix to your problem is very basic and I check that it's working in IE11, FF37 & Chrome42. What browser are you using? Any other clues?